# Finding value by specifying the class name

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery get field value of a telerik row(grid) by its class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584512/jquery-get-field-value-of-a-telerik-rowgrid-by-its-class)

I use telerik on MVC3

My grid has (event "onRowSelect(e)"):

`e.row.cells[1].innerHtml` //contain "myValue"

`e.row.cells[1].className` //contain "myClass"

How can I find the innerHtml According to className (jQuery - Find()?)

Comment: Have you tried .find() or do you not know how it works?

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584512/jquery-get-field-value-of-a-telerik-rowgrid-by-its-class)?

Comment: you may try `$(classname).text()` and it will return you the value according to the class

Comment: `$(e).find('myclass').html();`

Comment: I deleted the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God,

And thanks to everyone,

From everyone's comments, I found the correct answer:

```
$(e.row).find('myClass').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <div class="myDiv">Some text</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('.myDiv').text());
});
```

Will output:

> Some Text